# How to revoke alter table permission from user in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a user who only has permission to create dblinks, create session, and manage Scheduler, I want that it will not be able to create any object, delete it or alter it ... I already managed to prevent delete or create new things but I cannot remove the permission to make alters.

try with the following command with another user who has SYSDBA privileges:

REVOKE ALTER ON USER.TEST_LUIS FROM USER;

But the response tells me that I cannot remove permissions that have not been granted.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, it has SYSDBA privilege, i think the problem is that i cannot revoke permission on a user over its own objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't revoke alter privilege over objects from the user who owns them. You would need to remove the privilege to create them in the first place.

Example

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Sep 28 16:14:30 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> drop user test2 cascade ;

User dropped.

SQL> create user test2 identified by Oracle_1234 default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp_group account unlock profile default quota unlimited on users ;

User created.

SQL> grant create session , create table to test2 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

sqlplus test2/Oracle_1234

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Sep 28 16:13:24 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> create table t1 ( c1 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 add ( c2 number ) ;

Table altered.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Sep 28 16:14:30 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> revoke alter on test2.t1 from test2 ;
revoke alter on test2.t1 from test2
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant
```

In my example below, I can't revoke the privilege, because the user is the owner of the table.

I can revoke however the `create table` privilege

```
SQL> revoke create table from test2 ;

Revoke succeeded.
```

**Alter objects you own is inherited by the create privilege of the same object type.**

Comment: Thank you! i will create another user instead. :D